# How to determine column character set used on creation?

Tags: mysql, character-set

I have this SQL creation statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `testdb`.`new_table` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text_default` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `text_latin` VARCHAR(45) CHARACTER SET 'latin1' COLLATE 'latin1_swedish_ci' NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

where `testdb` has the default charset `latin1`.

Later, without knowing the create statement, **I want to figure out if a column was defined to have `latin1` as character set or it just inherited it from the database.**

### What I have tried

#### Export from the database using MySQLWorkbench

The `CHARACTER SET` instruction is not there.

#### Change the default character set of the table

```
ALTER TABLE `testdb`.`new_table` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Both columns `text_default` and `text_latin` preserve the `latin1` as charset.

#### Convert the whole table to another charset

ALTER TABLE testdb.new_table CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;

All columns are now `utf8`.

**So basically I found no solution to track back to creation if the column was specifically as `latin1` created.** Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This shows the collation and character set for one table:

```
SELECT column_name, 
       character_set_name, 
       collation_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name = 'your_table_name'
```

Comment: Both are at latin1. No distinction between them.